# 2017 BMW Alignment problems

Tags: bmw, alignment, x1

2017 BMW X1 - front tire blew out and when inspected the mechanic advised a special shim was needed to set the right front camber setting . BMW dealership did not know what I was talking about when I called them. Any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The [Camber Angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camber_angle) is the angle between the vertical axis of the wheel and the vertical axis of the vehicle - how much the wheel tilts in or out. On many cars it's quite common for it to be adjusted by adding or removing shims from behind the suspension arm mountings, however a hunt round Google suggests that on some modern BMWs it's adjusted using slotted nuts at the top of the strut.

The BMW dealership ought to know how to adjust it, whichever method is used!

Comment: Why would you have to adjust the camber setting on a fairly new and completely stock car? I'm not surprised that the dealer does not know anything about such modifications.

Comment: @MadMarky damage from a pothole causing misalignment? Incorrectly set from the factory (it's not unknown...)?